# Finding min in a stack- Won't print out any result

Tags: javascript, minimum, stack

Trying to find the min for this stack; however, whenever I run this in JSFiddle nothing prints out... anyone explain to me why? here's the code:

```
function min_stack() {
var min = 0; 
this.elements = [];

this.push = function(element) {
    this.elements.push(element);
}

this.pop = function() {
    return this.elements.pop();
}

this.min = function() {
    min = this.elements[0]; 
    if (this.elements.length > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
            if (min > this.elements[i]) {
                min = this.elements[i]; 
            }
        }
    }
    return min; 
   }
```

}

```
var myStack = new min_stack();
myStack.push(5);
myStack.push(4);
myStack.push(3);
print("[" + myStack.elements + "]");
print("min:" + myStack.min());
myStack.pop();
print("[" + myStack.elements + "]");
print("min:" + myStack.min());
myStack.pop();
print("[" + myStack.elements + "]");
print("min:" + myStack.min());
```

Comment: you are aware that `print()` will actually print the page? Do you mean to use `console.log` or `alert` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your `for` which shows up immediately in browser console

Change:

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
```

TO

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/y7wET/

ALso as pointed out in comments I doubt you want to use `print`

Answer (score 1):

`int i = 0;` is not valid JavaScript. JavaScript does not allow you to specify the type of a variable when declaring it; instead, use `var i = 0;`.

Also, because "window" is the global object, in the context of the Web page, print() is equivalent to [window.print()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.print), which prints the page to your printer.

For debugging purposes, you can pop up a message box using [window.alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert); if that is too annoying, you could do something such as adding your output to a textarea element instead.